# Exporting data to excel in C# with comma delimited issue

Tags: c#, excel

The problem is not the exporting itself but how it separates the fields with comma's and I have commas in the fields. All works fine until it gets to the last field where the string contains a comma, it delimits it

My code:

```
  foreach (var item in jobSortedReportData)
  {
       sb.Append("\"").Append(item.Title).Append("\",\"").Append(item.Total).Append("\",\"").Append(item.Week6).Append("\",\"").Append(item.Week5).Append("\",\"").Append(item.Week4).Append("\",\"").Append(item.Week3).Append("\",\"").Append(item.Week2).Append("\",").Append(item.Week1).Append(Environment.NewLine);                     
  }

  byte[] textBytes2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
```

the output this generates:

```
 Number 1 Job Search    0   **Bathroom Fitter, Plumbing: 100**  Carpenter, Joinery: 99  Carpenter, Joinery: 81  Carpenter, Joinery: 209 Electrician, Domestic Electrical: 495   **Bathroom Fitter    Plumbing: 112**
 Number 2 Job Search    0   Carpenter, Joinery: 97  Bathroom Fitter, Plumbing: 99   Bathroom Fitter, Plumbing: 79   Bathroom Fitter, Plumbing: 150  Bathroom Fitter, Plumbing: 453  Builder  Window Installation: 75
 Number 3 Job Search    0   Builder, Window Installation: 85    Building Contractor, Kitchen Fitting: 97    Plumber, Bathroom Fitting: 51   Builder, Window Installation: 134   Heating Engineer, Gas Installation: 451 Bathroom Fitter  Bathroom Fitting: 74
```

raw view:

```
"Number 3 Job Search","0","Builder, Window Installation: 85","Building Contractor, Kitchen     Fitting: 97","Plumber, Bathroom Fitting: 51","Builder, Window Installation: 134","Heating Engineer, Gas Installation: 451",Bathroom Fitter, Bathroom Fitting: 74 
"Number 1 Tradesmen Search","0","Painter & Decorator: 316","Painter & Decorator: 229","Painter & Decorator: 146","Builder: 324","TV Aerials & In-home Entertainment Installer: 1378",Electrician: 247 
"Number 2 Tradesmen Search","0","Builder: 171","Builder: 191","Plumber: 114","Plumber: 295","Builder: 551",Builder: 205 
"Number 3 Tradesmen Search","0","Plumber: 123","Plumber: 160","Builder: 108","Painter & Decorator: 231","Domestic Electrical: 495",Painter & Decorator: 160
```

In the above, `"Bathroom Fitter, Plumbing: 100"` in the 3rd column contains a `,` but it keeps the whole string in one excel field. When it comes to the last column `"Bathroom Fitter   Plumbing: 112"` there is a `,` in the string between *Fitter* and *Plumbing*, so what happens now is this , is seen as a separator so when in excel it split this in **TWO** cells, thus I have `Bathroom Fitter` in one cell and `Plumbing:112` in the next. The whole string should be in ONE cell. It does this only on the last column?? please help me correct this.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the RAW CSV data? I can't see quotes in the provided data..

Comment: First of all, add @ in front of your strings (like @"\"), it tells the string constructor to ignore escape characters.

Comment: please see OP for raw view,thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its hard to see with out the raw csv but rememeber that you need to use text qualifiers if a CSV field contains commas to prevent it thinking it is a column. So the raw CSV should look like this to get consistent results:

"Bathroom Fitter, Plumbing: 100",next column, "column with comma".

EDIT: Now I have seen the raw shouldn't the code look like this at the end?  I don't think your adding the text qualifiers on the last field:

```
...Append(item.Week2).Append("\",\"").Append(item.Week1).Append("\"").Append(Environment.NewLine);
```

Answer (score 0):

CSV output is one of those things that everyone seems to roll on their own, only to inevitably find out later that there's some case they forgot about and wished they'd just grabbed a library to do for them. CsvHelper (https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper) is one I used. I believe it's a pretty common solution.